# How can i make selected cells a range for a loop?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, foreach, range

I'm working with a Pivot Table and i want to hide all rows in the Grand Total column that show a total of between -1 and 1.  In VBA i can hide all of those rows and it works as intended if i specify the exact range e.g ("J5:J100"), however the number of columns will change throughout the month so i need the range to be dynamic.

I'm hoping this is something really simple that I'm missing but i just can't see it.
The code in theory will locate and select the last column, make that selection a range, loop through the range hiding all rows that are of minimal value.

Any ideas?

Current code:

```
Sub Hide_Rows()
'
' HideRows Macro
'
' Selects Last Column of Pivot Table
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
    .Offset(1, .Columns.Count - 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Select
End With
   
' Set variables
Dim selection As Range
Dim Cell As Range
Dim rng As Range

' Make the selection a range to run the loop through
Set rng = selection

' Loop to hide all cells between -1 & 1
  For Each Cell In rng `(THIS IS WHERE THE CODE STOPS)`
    If Cell.Value < 1 And Cell.Value > -1 Then
      Cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
     End If
  Next Cell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You must not use a variable called `selection` as this is a reserved word in excel vba - delete `Dim selection as range` - and pretty sure your code will work.

Comment: @Ike Thanks so much mate, that did it. I knew it'd be something simple. Just couldn't see it. Much appreciated!